# How do I override the default Angular scss that show up in the autogenerated styles file?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm working in an Angular 11 project, and I have not been able to figure out how to use the styles.scss file to override styles that are define on Angular material components.  For instance I am trying to override the border color of a mat-form-field to be rgba(221,221,221,0.5) but a style defined in the autogenerated  file is overriding my change.  I have tried using ng-deep which doesn't seem to work in the styles.scss file and I have already modified my angular.json to define the order that style files are applied to be:

```html
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@custom-theme/angular-material-theme/ads-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

How do I override this autogenerated style?

[image: Inspecting element in Chrome shows overridden style]

Answer (score 1):

the "key" is use "[css cascade and specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#specificity_2)"

e.g. if you add to your **styles.scss** (should be in a global style)

```
//see that we want change the .mat-form-field-outline,
//so you use ".custom.mat-form-field "+class to override
.custom.mat-form-field .mat-form-field-outline{
   color: green;
}
```

you see the border green in a

```
<mat-form-field class="custom" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can try also override using `!important` or, in sometimes is unnecesary add the "custom" class